# Хочу добавить коды страниц в source.html но выскакивает ошибка TypeError: write() argument must be str, not BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = input("> ")
r = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'})
stat = r.status_code
s = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
file = open("source.html", "w")
file.write(s)
file.close()
if stat == 200:
    print("Content saved")
else:
    print("The URL returned ", stat, "!")
```

Comment: Ну можете попробовать `file.write(r.text)`, но вообще в BS лучше передавать `r.content`, например, а не как вы делаете. Зачем вы пытаетесь записать в файл объект `BeautifulSoup`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = input("> ")
r = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'})
stat = r.status_code
s = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
with open("source.html", "w", encoding='UTF-8') as file:
    file.write(str(s))
if stat == 200:
    print("Content saved")
else:
    print("The URL returned ", stat, "!")
```